# Windows IoT Web Server Not Working

Tags: windowsiot, raspberry-pi3

If I start up a web server exactly how they do it in the [BlinkyWebServer](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/BlinkyWebServer.htm) example, everything appears to work correctly while debugging (no errors), but I can't access the url on the port.  I just get a timeout.  I'm using the 14295 build of Windows IoT with a Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of build 14295 Windows IoT added an internal firewall.  To open up a port:

1. [Connect to your device in powershell](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm)
2. Open up the firewall with:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=[Any name to identify rule] dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=[Port number]
   ```